# python pyautogui doesn't release enter

Tags: python, pyautogui

This is my code:

```
from pyHM import mouse
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

url = 'https://google.com'
call(['chrome', '--incognito'])
mouse.move(600, 100, multiplier=1)
mouse.click(600, 100)
pyautogui.typewrite(f'{url}\n')
```

Also other attempts of mine (I only add the lines change comparing the first code):

```
url = 'https://google.com\n'
pyautogui.typewrite(f'{url}')
```

Other one (whole code):

```
from subprocess import call
from pyHM import mouse
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

url = 'https://google.com'
call(['chrome', '--incognito'])
mouse.move(600, 100, multiplier=1)
mouse.click(600, 100)

pyperclip.copy(url)
with pyautogui.hold('ctrl'):
    pyautogui.press('v')
pyautogui.keyDown("enter")
pyautogui.keyUp('enter')
```

But the issue is it seems the key is not released. When I manually press the `enter` button in the address bar, the website loads. But if I don't do this, the `rounding circle` in the browser which indicates the site is still loading, that is seen in the web browser window.

I also tried this:

```
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.keyUp('enter')
```

But it still doesn't work.

**Update 1**

I reached a workaround for myself but not a permanent solution maybe:

```
call(['chrome', '--incognito'])
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('f12')
sleep(1)
mouse.move(600, 100, multiplier=1)
mouse.click(600, 100)

pyperclip.copy(url)
with pyautogui.hold('ctrl'):
    pyautogui.press('v')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.press('f12')
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do but it kinda looks like you have "up" and "down" confused.

Comment: @Woodford that was a typo in the question. I edited.

Comment: If you use Selenium, you can control Chrome directly through its API, without any simulated keystroke or mouse click hackery.

Comment: @TimRoberts for some reasons I need to control the mouse directly. I tried Selenium but doesn't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `Enter key` doesn't get released after pressing it with `pyautogui`, so to fix this, you can use the `keyUp` method of `pyautogui` right after pressing Enter!!! and it's also a good idea to add a short delay after pressing Enter to make sure the key is released before doing anything else. you can adjust the delay time based on what you need, because this delay gives the browser enough time to process the Enter key and load the webpage properly!

```
from subprocess import call
from pyHM import mouse
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

url = 'https://google.com'
call(['chrome', '--incognito'])
mouse.move(600, 100, multiplier=1)
mouse.click(600, 100)

pyperclip.copy(url)
with pyautogui.hold('ctrl'):
    pyautogui.press('v')
    
pyautogui.press('enter')
sleep(0.5)  #you can add a delay after pressing Enter here!

pyautogui.keyUp('enter')
```

and if it's not working for you, try this alternative approach: instead of using `pyautogui.press('enter')` and `pyautogui.keyUp('enter')`, you can give `pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])` a shot, this will mimic the action of pressing and releasing the enter key. Give it a whirl and see if it does the trick for you

```
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
```